# are there high-dimensional knots with non-trivial normal bundle?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Does there exist a smooth embedding $\varphi\colon S^k\to S^n$  such that $\varphi(S^k)$ has non-trivial normal bundle?
I looked at some of the old papers by Kervaire, Haefliger, Massey, Levine but I couldn't find an answer.
There are various related results, for example it is shown by Kervaire et al that in many dimensions the normal bundle is trivial. Furthermore Kervaire showed that there exists an immersion, such that the pullback of the normal bundle is non-trivial.

Comment: If k<2(n-k)-1 then the normal bundle is trivial by a result of Kervaire (Theorem 8.2 in his "An Interpretation of G. Whitehead's Generalization of H. Hopf's Invariant"). If n=k+1,k+2,k+3 it is trivial as well.

Comment: Using this, one sees that all embeddings with $k\le 6$ have trivial normal bundle. I believe it is an open question whether there is an embedding with nontrivial normal bundle for k=7 and n=11.

Comment: Do you know if Kervaire's example $\nu$ is stably trivial? Maybe I'm oversimplifying, but if you have an immersion $f : S^k \to S^n$ with $k < n$, then it factorises as $i_n\circ f_0$ where $i_n : \mathbb{R}^n \to S^n$ is the standard inclusion and $f_0 : S^k \to \mathbb{R}^n$. The map $h : S^k \to S^{n+k+1}$ given by $i_{n+k+1}\circ(f_0, \iota)$ is an embedding where $\iota: S^k \to \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ is the standard embedding. If I'm not mistaken, the normal bundle of $h$ is $\nu\oplus\varepsilon^{k+1}$ which is trivial if and only if $\nu$ is stably trivial.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Any normal bundle arising from such an embedding is stably trivial, since the tangent bundle of $S^k$ is.

Comment: According to Hsiang, Lee, and Szczarba, it is an unpublished result of Haefliger that $S^{11}$ embedds into $S^{17}$ with trivial normal bundle (see 'On the normal bundle of a homotopy sphere embedded in Euclidean space'). This would show that Kervaire's bound is sharp.

Comment: @archipelago  thanks for your comments! But from you and I unearthed so far in the literature it could in principle be that the normal bundle is always trivial, isn't it? You'd think that this question was answered in the 60's.

Comment: @archipelago: Of course, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @archipelago   Since Levine was my advisor I should point out that it's a paper by Hsiang, Levine and Szcarba

Comment: @archipelago but for this conversation it's more important that by accident you misquoted their comment, they write "since Haefliger (unpublished) has shown that S^11 embeds in R^17 with a +++++non-trivial++++ normal
bundle." That's a very good find and answers my question with a shaky reference. It would be great if there was a reference with details

Comment: more googling gives an answer in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237384/is-the-normal-bundle-of-a-torus-trivial.

Comment: Namely Danny Ruberman writes: "Jerry Levine's paper "A classification of differentiable knots" (Annals 82 (1965) 15-50) determines (see proposition 6.2) the possible normal bundles in some range of codimensions in terms of maps in various exact sequences. It's hard to summarize the results, but he gives a table at the end dealing with relatively low dimensions, where calculations can be made explicit. The case n=11 and k=6 contains Haefliger's example; in fact there are exactly 5 possible normal bundles among all embeddings."

Comment: @archipelago   thanks, you put me on the right track!

Comment: @StefanFriedl Thanks for the corrections.